# Какая модель памяти в .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

В спецификации ECMA CLI определена слабая (weak) модель памяти. Это позволяет переупорядочивать последовательность выполнения команд (что полезно для производительности). Но писать низкоуровневый код для такой модели очень тяжело.

А главное - архитектуры процессоров X86/AMD64 имеют более строгую (strong) модель памяти. В итоге Microsoft в своей реализации CLR реализовала более строгую модель памяти, чем описано в спецификации.

Изменилась ли модель памяти в .NET Core? Потенциально, этот фреймворк может работать на архитектурах с более слабой, чем X86/AMD64, моделью памяти.

К тому же, Core вбирает в себя Mono и прочее. А насколько мне известно, модель памяти Mono более слабая, соответствует ECMA.

О чём вообще речь: [Memory Model](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cbrumme/memory-model/)

Comment: Задал этот вопрос на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58693683/5045688

Comment: А чего не приняли ответ на английском SO? Вроде дело ответили вам.

Comment: @aepot - я надеялся на появление какого-то официального документа от команды разработчиков .NET Core, с чётким описанием модели. Или же, что в тему заглянет кто-то наподобие Рихтера, Тауба и тому подобных небожителей.

Comment: За такими штуками надо бы на гитхаб идти. :) А так, даже в теории, что [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice) может поменяться?

Comment: @aepot - я эту статью читал раньше. Она основана именно на ECMA CLI и не совпадает с реализацией MS CLR.

Comment: Что-то бот апнул вопрос, быть может перетянете сюда информацию в ответ, да примете? Полезно будет для других посетителей.

Comment: Свершилось: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/specs/Memory-model.md

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight - я наконец-то нашёл время и прочитал документ. Спасибо! В нём содержатся все ответы на мои вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.NET memory model](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/specs/Memory-model.md) - документ содержит удовлетворяющую меня информацию.

Кратко: модель память дотнета остаётся сильной. Она доказала свою надёжность, полностью устраивает разработчиков и поддерживается всеми современными аппаратными средствами (других, собственно, нет).

В будущем, если появится оборудование с более слабой моделью памяти, то в реализации рантайма будет использоваться принудительное выравнивание/упорядочивание.

Comment: *"В будущем, если появится оборудование с более слабой моделью памяти, то в реализации рантайма будет использоваться принудительное выравнивание"* - однако по ссылке написано, что оно уже используется *"When managed by the .NET runtime, variables of built-in primitive types are properly aligned according to the data type size."*